# Play Youtube videos in Video View in android

Tags: android, video, youtube

I am developing a youtube player in android. I am getting the rtsp video correct url. But still the video is not playing. Please help to me to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Here is my code

```
String youtubeURL="rtsp://v6.cache4.c.youtube.com/CigLENy73wIaHwmh5W2TKCuN2RMYDSANFEgGUgx1c2VyX3VwbG9hZHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp";
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_online_video_player);

       videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_View);

       progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(OnlineVideoPlayer.this, "", "Buffering video...",true);
       progressDialog.setCancelable(false);


       PlayVideo();
}

private void PlayVideo()
{
       try {
           final VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_View);
     //1   //mediaController = new MediaController(Splashscreen.this);
     //2   //mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
           // Set video link (mp4 format )
           Uri video = Uri.parse(youtubeURL);
           //videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
           videoView.setVideoURI(video);
           videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
               public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
                  videoView.start();
               }
           });

        }catch(Exception e){
             progressDialog.dismiss();
            System.out.println("Video Play Error :"+e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: This code is working , maybe the problem is in your xml file , could you please post it

Comment: I don't think your url is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another working code

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_view);

    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("rtsp://r2---sn-a5m7zu76.c.youtube.com/Ck0LENy73wIaRAnTmlo5oUgpQhMYESARFEgGUg5yZWNvbW1lbmRhdGlvbnIhAWL2kyn64K6aQtkZVJdTxRoO88HsQjpE1a8d1GxQnGDmDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();


}
```

activity_video_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Awseome code.  Please tell me how to generat rstp link of any youtube cideo?

Comment: hey, how did you get a rstp link from YouTube? Please tell! Very need

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. Use [YouTubeAndroidApi](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) for playing YouTube videos.

Comment: but what if you need to play both regular video (from sources like http://example.com/sample.mp4) and youtube video. Seems stupid to have two views just to be able to play both type of videos.

Comment: Users need to run version 4.2.16 of the mobile YouTube app (or higher) to use the YouTube Android Player API.

Comment: Now its deprecated, so any alternative @RomanBlack

Answer (score 2):

There might be many reasons to not play the video,You can test it on other devices also set
   android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest

try following listeners to get correct issue

```
playerview.setOnPreparedListener(preparelistener);
        playerview.setOnErrorListener(errorlistenr);
        playerview.setOnCompletionListener(completelistener);
```