# Play videos inside and android app

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

I am trying to play a video inside my app. Now as a source I only have the public URL of the video, e.g

> www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OnPN6YxPuc

Can i use this to play the video inside the app, like using the videoView or MediaPlayer or something like that? The video can be from any provider, not specifically from Youtube e.g Vimeo, Dailymotion etc.

Currently i am using intent on click and it opens the browser or some app if installed and plays the video there. I want it to play inline. Webview is an option but the problem is Android v 4 > has good HTML5 support n bad Flash support, and <4 have good flash and bad HTMl5.

Is it the only option i have? Any pointers would be a great help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play YouTube video in my Android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654878/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-my-android-application)

or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278633/play-youtube-videos-in-video-view-in-android

Comment: @user3439968 thanks man, but i have seen those questions and a lot of others too, but they dont answer my question. Firstly, i want a generic solution, not specific to a site(youtube in this case). Secondly, i want to know if the webview approach would work and any pointers if someone has tried it already.